# diffeomorphic closed manifolds are cobordant

Tags: differential-topology

Two closed oriented $n-1$ dimenisonal manifolds $A,B$ are cobordant if there is a compact $n$ dimensional manifold $M$ such that $A \sqcup -B$ diffeomorphic(orientation-preserving) to boundry of $M$.

If there is a diffeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ , can we conclude that $A,B$ are cobordant? Intuitively, I think it is true, but I have trouble to prove this claim.

Comment: Is not this is the right definition: Two oriented closed $n-1$ dimensional manifolds $A, B$ are said to cobordant if there is a compact $n$ dimensional oriented manifold $M$ such that there is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism from $\partial M$ to $A\sqcup -B$

Comment: how about $A\times [0,1]$?

Comment: @Timkinsella, you are right. If there is an orientation preserving diffeomorphism from $A$ to $B$, then $A\times [0,1]$ is the right choice for $M$.

Comment: @Sumanta you are right. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Timkinsella why $A×[0,1]$ works for any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism?

Comment: @iefjkfdhfure    The boundary of the $1$-dimensional smooth manifold $[0, 1]$ with the usual orientation, i.e. from $0$ to $1$, is **defined** as $\big(−\{0\}\big) \cup \{1\}$. Also, for any two oriented manifold $X,Y$ with $\partial Y=\varnothing$ we have $$\partial (X\times Y)=(\partial X)\times Y\textbf{ as oriented manifolds.}$$